# What does it mean to have at most n distinct conjugates?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have an understanding problem in the following exercise:

> Let $G$ be a finite Group. Let $H\subset G$ be a strict subgroup of $G$. Show that $G$ can not be equal to the union $\bigcup_{g\in G} gHg^{-1}$. Said differentyl there exists an element $h\in G$ s.t. $h\notin gHg^{-1}$ for any $g\in G$. Hint: If $n=card(G/H)$ show that $H$ has at most $n$ distinct conjugates.

I somehow don't understand the hint. So I don't know how to think about conjugates. do they mean the conjugacy classes of $H$?

Could someone maybe explain me what this means, so you don't have to solve the exercise, only explain what this hint really mean.

Thanks a lot.

My approach would be as follows:

Let us take $x,y\in zH\in G/H$ and denote $x=zh, y=zh'$. Then $$xHx^{-1}=(zh)H(h^{-1}z^{-1})=z(hHh^{-1})z^{-1}=zHz^{-1}=z(h'Hh'^{-1})z^{-1}=(zh)H(h'^{-1}z^{-1})=yHy^{-1}$$.

This shows that for two elements in the same coset, the conjugates are equal. Since we have $n$ cosets this means that there are at most $n$ conjugates.

Comment: The conjugates of $H$ are the subgroups $g^{-1}Hg$ for $g\in G$.

Comment: ah okey perfect thanks!

Comment: @EricTowers can one deduce this fact that beeing conjugate is an equivalence relation, i.e. $$G=\dot\bigcup gHg^{-1}$$ (this should be the disjoint union

Comment: I see your point thanks. But as I understood it correctly the conjugates of H are not equal to the conjugacy class of an element $x\in G$ right?

Comment: Let's go with a different question...  Can you think of an element of $G$, guaranteed to be an element of $H$, that is not moved by conjugation?

Comment: The only thing I think of is the identity

Comment: I added the first part I done to show the hint is this correct now? My problem is that I know that we want to show that $$\left|\bigcup gHg^{-1}\right|<|G|$$ but how can we do this using the hint?

Comment: Let $G$ have $m$ elements, let $H$ have $r$ elements, let $n=m/r$ so there are $n$ conjugates, each conjugate has $r$ elements, and each conjugate has the identity element. What more do you need?

Comment: sorry I don't see what to do with this, could you maybe explain a bit more?

Comment: So you have $n$ conjugates of $H$.  All of them have the identity in $G$, $e$, in common.  What's the maximum number of elements of $G$ in those $n$ conjugates of $H$?

Comment: So I would say that we have $\left|\bigcup gHg^{-1}\right|\leq 1+\left| \bigcup gHg^{-1}\setminus \{e\}\right|$$ is this correct?